# How do I retrieve a variable from .js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I access a variable defined in a js file from a vue file? Is there a way to pass this variable to the vue file? In the code below, I've got a `template.js` file and a `contact.vue` file. I am converting mjml to html in the template file and I need to access the output saved to the `plainHmtl` variable from the vue file.

template.js

```
const mjml2html = require('mjml')
const Vue = require('vue')

const app = new Vue({
    data: {
        name: ''
    },
    template: `
<mj-section>
  <mj-column>
    <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="helvetica">Hello {{ name }}</mj-text>
  </mj-column>
</mj-section>`
})

const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer({
    template: `
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
  </mj-body>
</mjml>`
})

renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
    const htmlWithoutDataServerRenderedAttribute = html.replace(`data-server-rendered="true"`, '')
    const plainHtml = mjml2html(htmlWithoutDataServerRenderedAttribute)
    console.log(plainHtml.html)
})
```

contact.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="sign_up" id="signupform">
     <main role="main">
      <div class="SignUp_container">
      <form class="form-signup" @submit.prevent="processForm">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required/>
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required/>
      <input type="email" name="mailaddr" placeholder="Your email address" required/>
      <div class="sign_cancel_buttons">
      <router-link to="/">
        <button id="canlbtn" type="cancel" class="clbtn">
          Cancel
        </button>
         </router-link> 
        <button id="signupbtn" type="submit" name="sendmsg-button" class="signbtn">
          Sign Up
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
     </main>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       methods: {
       
       // how do I access plainHtml here?
       
       }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In template.js, define a variable where you will have the final result of converting your html, once defined just add this to the end of the file:

```
export { varHTML }
```

Now in contact.vue you have to import and use the export we made from template.js, consider that you must modify the import path according to the case that you are handling for your files:

```
import { varHTML } from './template.js'
<script>
   export default {
       data() {
         return {
           plainHtml: null
         }
       }
       methods: {
         // how do I access plainHtml here?
       
         // any method that is going to be needed now will have plainHtml available
       },
       created () {
         this.plainHtml = varHTML
       }
   }
 </script>
```